# How to make this type of logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

[image]

this logo looks so clean. is this created manually by adjusting path or there is a trick?
thx.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. As initially posted your query is very broad, and thus hard to answer - can you be more specific in what you're trying to find out?  Please read [ask] and [edit]  your question to better fit our guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. I can't say how this logo was made, but I'm sure it's possible to create something like this manually only using 3 circles and 5 separate paths. The 5 individual paths seems to be smooth (no split handles) and each go through each of the 3 circles. It's simpler than you think. Try drawing 3 circles and then draw just one of the 5 smooth paths with the pen tool. When it looks good, duplicate it and adjust a little bit here and there.

Answer (score 2):

Make a closed path which has a few, say 3 or 4 nodes. Make a copy and edit its handles with the direct selection tool, beware moving the nodes!

Make a few step blend between these 2 versions, expand and ungroup the blend to get free objects. Move the objects so that the nodes fit.

Color with a gradient. Draw and insert the black dots if they really are needed.

The geometry part without colors is shown in the next example:

[image]

You can easily explore variations without sacrificing the smooth transitions between the curves if you put the 2 versions to the same place before making the blend. The blend adapts if you edit a handle or move the nodes.

You can also apply envelope distortion to the result. Here's an example of applying warp to the same shape: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5l6jcwpqwzp44x/2Hunt1862.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Thank youuuu so muchhhhhhhhh for thisss, the idea of using circle never crossed in my mindddd thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhh again